# How to get Home Button as MenuItem android

Tags: android, menuitem, android-toolbar

I am setting my toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

How can I retrieve the home button (`android.R.id.home`) as a `MenuItem`?

Here's what I tried:

```
MenuItem back = menu.findItem(android.R.id.home);
```

But that makes a `NullPointerException` for some reason. So how can I retrieve it as `MenuItem` without getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Why do you want to get a reference to it? There's plenty of methods for interacting with it

Comment: @digithree I want to get the reference of the home (aka back) button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't find out  to get it as a `MenuItem`, but, to disable the home button pogrammatically:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true/false)
```

This is what I needed. But I still didn't find out how to get it as a `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 2):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114376/781729), suggests the following code **but it doesn't seem to work** and I can't find anything else.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home);
```

In any case it is hacky, because you *shouldn't need that reference*, and you shouldn't be traversing the view hierarchy to get it in any case. Since the Android SDK purposefully hides this from you, it is not something you should attempt to get, as even if the above code did work, it may not work in a future version (which actually seems like a possible explanation for it not working for me as I tested in SDK 23 Marshmallow).

So, if you want to set the icon, you can do it by setting the `android:homeAsUpIndicator` in your theme, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14140880/781729).

If you want to detect a click event on the home button, the correct way is by overriding the [`onOptionsItemSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) method of [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)), for example

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // do something
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any other use would be outside the intended purpose and so not supported, as is agreed by others such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27723539/781729).

Comment: Since it's bad practice, is there an alternative?

Comment: Using this code: `MenuItem back = (MenuItem) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home);
` I still get `null`

Comment: Well for a start, `findViewById` will return a `View`, and since `MenuItem` is not a subclass of `View` you cannot cast the object returned by `findViewById` to a `MenuItem`. But it doesn't work in any case. I assumed it would since the answer said it did and was accepted. I'll update the answer

Comment: My use case for wanting to get a reference to that home button is so that I can tooltip/showcase/onboarding on it. I apply a different icon to that button (tapping it loads a filter menu). I want to do an onboarding tooltip kind of feature pointing at that button to tell users what that button is for. I want to reference that button so I can get its screen position/size to properly place my tooltip.